# Set OMP_PLACES options in Rcpp with openmp

Tags: variables, openmp, rcpp, environment

Can anyone please tell me what will be the right way to set the omp_places option in Rcpp? I would like to set the option to "OMP_PLACES=cores"  Thank you so much!
My function looks like this:

```
// [[Rcpp::plugins(openmp)]]
// [[Rcpp::export]]
Rcpp::List func1(const arma::vec & x, const arma::vec & y){

    #pragma omp parallel proc_bind(spread) num_threads(2) 
    {
      #pragma omp for  
      for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){    // for-loop 1
        some calculation
      }
    
      #pragma omp for 
      for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){   // for-loop 2
        some calculation
      }
    }

return Rcpp::List::create(Rcpp::Named("variable 1") = v1,
                          Rcpp::Named("variable 2") = v2);
}
```

Comment: `OMP_PLACES` appears to be related to cpu affinity pinning. Which is not something R lets you do as far as I know.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel Thank you for the quick explanation! I did some search but just cannot find the answer. It's good to know this is not doable inside R.

Comment: `OMP_PLACES` is an environment variable. It must be set in the environment of the parallel executable, which in your case is the R interpreter itself.

Comment: Note that even if you use whatever R equivalent there is of "setenv", you cannot easily be sure that that it will have any effect, since the OpenMP implementation does not have to re-read the envirable each time it starts a parallel region. Rather it parses it once at OpenMP startup time, so if there is some other OpenMP invocation hidden away inside R somewhere, and that happens before any of your code executes, changing the envirable in your code will have no effect.